# Debugging preview-latex

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

Running `preview-latex` in *Emacs 25* on *Ubuntu 18.04* once worked for me, but now inserts warning icons instead of rendered images of the formular snippets.

A minimal example, which **doesn't** work is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a = 1$
\end{document}
```

I carefully read the *preview-latex* manual on https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html which mentions issues with `gs < version 9.27` on https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html#Known-problems.

The combination of tools used by `preview-latex` to generate preview image snippets is not trivial and indeed, I don't see any `preview.dsc` or `*.png` files generated by it on my setup.

*Ubuntu 18.04* ships with `gs version 9.26`, but the solution suggested in *preview-latex*'s section on known issues doesn't work, because the `preview-pdf-adjust-color-method` variable doesn't exist on *Emacs 25*.

Which additional diagnostics could I run to pin down the problem?

Comment: Which version of AUCTeX are you using, and how did you install it?

Comment: My AUCTeX version is 11.91 (installed as an Ubuntu package).

Comment: 11.91 is about 7 years old.  Uninstall that package and install AUCTeX from ELPA with `M-x list-packages <RET>`, mark the `auctex` package for installation with `i`, and hit `x` to execute the installation procedure.  You should get the version 13.2.4.  If that doesn't work, download the [tarball](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/auctex-13.2.4.tar.lz), uncompress and use `M-x package-install-file RET` to install it.